# Delete, fadeout and remove comment

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade

When I delete a comment the rowCount is not updated to not contain the actual number of comments.
Because I use the fadeout function and not the remove() function because I want it to fade out from view.

How can i first fadeout and then remove?

Have tried this but that did nto help:

```
$('#item_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

#### The Code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "delete-comment.php", 
    dataType:"text", 
    data:myData, 
    success: function(response){
        $('#item_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut("slow");
        var rowCount = $('#comment li').length;
        alert(rowCount);
        return false;   
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

#### EDIT:

Here is my full code. Can it be mode simple?

```
    //##### Send delete Ajax request to response.php #########
$("body").on("click", "#comment .del_button", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //e.returnValue = false;
    var clickedID = this.id.split('-'); //Split string (Split works as PHP explode)
    var DbNumberID = clickedID[1]; //and get number from array
    var myData = 'action=delete&id='+ DbNumberID; //build a post data structure

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "add-comment.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
        dataType: "text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        data: myData, //Form variables
        success: function(response){
            //on success, hide  element user wants to delete.
            $('#item_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut(500, function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#item_'+DbNumberID).remove();
                }, 500);
            });

            var rowCount = $('#comment li').length;
            rowCount--;
            alert(rowCount);

            if (rowCount == 0) {    
                $("#comment").html('<div class="PageWarning">No comments.</div></div>');    
            }
            return false;
        },

        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            //On error, we alert user
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle to illustrate?

Comment: So this doesn't _work_ after the `setTimeout` too? Time to post your generated HTML too :)

Comment: It does......... But can my main code be more simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a bit hacky but you could set a timeOut with duration as long as your fadeOut

```
$('#item_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut(500, function() {
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#item_'+DbNumberID).remove();
}, 500);
});
```

you could also try

```
$('#item_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut('slow').queue(function(next) {
$(this).remove();
next();
});
```

http://cdmckay.org/blog/2010/06/22/how-to-use-custom-jquery-animation-queues/

Comment: Yes that works. - I do this to show there are not more comments

Comment: when this works its perfect, as your code is tiny... thousand ways to Rome, i would rather do this a bit more like send the whole list as answer to the request and update the the list, there are many easy ways using json. but if your current state works just perfect without any disadvantages ..use it, but no guarantees from me, idon´t even know why the fadeOut(callback) doesn´t work

Answer (score 0):

The answer has already been selected but I'll answer anyway to make this page more useful :)

#### your "success" handler

```
    success: function(response){
        //on success, hide  element user wants to delete.
        $('#item_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut(500, function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#item_'+DbNumberID).remove();
            }, 500);
        });

        var rowCount = $('#comment li').length;
        rowCount--;
        alert(rowCount);

        if (rowCount == 0) {    
            $("#comment").html('<div class="PageWarning">No comments.</div></div>');    
        }
        return false;
    },
```

This is *hackey*, as mentioned by john smith, but it doesn't have to be. The actual problem is that your overlooking that fact that `fade()` doesn't halt the execution of the code. The moment `fade(500)` completes, the code following the `fade(500)` call has already run and has returned you the number of rows, which is obviously what you don't expect because fade is still running.
A proper solution to this problem is to wrap all code that depends on the outcome of `fade()` in *fade complete callback* as follows

```
success: function(response){

    var rowCount = $('#comment li').length;

    //on success, hide  element user wants to delete.
    $('#item_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut(500, function() {
    
        $('#item_'+DbNumberID).remove();
        
        /* the code that has been moved into this callback */
        rowCount = $('#comment li').length;

        alert(rowCount);

        if (rowCount == 0) {    
            $("#comment").html('<div class="PageWarning">No comments.</div></div>');    
        }
    });
    return false;
},
```